# Sqark SQL percentile function returns wrong results

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

percentile functions value returned is not in the given set, where percentile_approx is, i am not able to understand why , need help.

query is

```
SELECT percentile(cl,0.2),percentile_approx(cl,0.2) from (SELECT explode(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) as cl)
```

results

```
percentile|percentile_approx
1.8       | 1
```

where as for  MEDIAN(50TH PERCENTILE) values are matching and accurate.

```
SELECT percentile(cl,0.5),percentile_approx(cl,0.5) from (SELECT explode(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) as cl)
```

```
percentile|percentile_approx
 3.0       |       3
```